# Is there any way to tell 64-bit GHC to treat Int as Int32?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm writing a Haskell to Javascript code generator, using GHC as a library. Since Javascript doesn't have an integer type and its Number type can only represent integers up to 2⁵³ properly, I'm representing integers as Numbers, explicitly performing all arithmetic modulo 2³². This works very well with a 32 bit GHC, but rather worse with the 64 bit version.

GHC will happily coerce Int64 values to Ints and interpret Int constants as 64 bit values (0xffffffff turns into 4294967295 rather than -1, for example) and that's causing all sorts of annoying problems.

The compiler works very well for "normal" web stuff even on a 64 bit system, provided that the standard libraries are built on a 32 bit machine, but "please don't use large-ish numbers, OK?" isn't something you want to see in your compiler's manual. Some of the problems (but not all) can be alleviated by compiling with -O0, but that (unsurprisingly) produces code that's not only slow, but also way too big.

So, I need to stop GHC from assuming that Int and Int64 are equivalent. Is this even possible?

Comment: If you want 32-bit integers, why not use `GHC.Int.Int32`?

Comment: That is indeed possible, but "you have to use Int32 rather than Int because Int is broken" isn't something you want to see in your compiler's manual either.

Comment: What promise made about `Int` is broken?

Comment: No need to even import GHC-specific modules. `Data.Int` contains `Int32` (it's re-exported from `GHC.Int` in GHC but that shouldn't matter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not possible, without using a 32 bit GHC.

The [Haskell Language standard says](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch18.html#x26-22400018.1) that the only thing you know about the `Int` type is that it has

> at least the range [-2^29 .. 2^29-1

So you can happily truncate `Int` values larger than this, and still be a fully compliant Haskell 2010 implementation!

However, you should probably not do this, and instead look for a 64 bit integer type for JavaScript. The same trick as e.g. GHC does to support `Int64` on 32 bit machines.

Comment: Switching everything to some 64 bit type like the Long class from Google's Closure library would indeed solve the problem, but would blow up code size and absolutely murder performance; that seems like a hefty price to pay when the vast majority of code would be quite happy with 32 bits.

Truncating Int values is a far more attractive option, but since GHC is seemingly coercing Int64 values to Int (even when those values are explicitly typed), that's going to potentially break any code that actually uses Int64.

Comment: It's JavaScript -- how good is the performance going to be anyway. I'd rather have it slow and correct, than silently wrong numbers.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily hurt performance.  GHC's performance with `Int`-sized `Integer`s is nearly equivalent to using `Int`s directly, why couldn't an equivalent Javascript library do the same?  Although I still think you should just use `Int32`.

Comment: DonStewart: performance is going to suck anyway, true, but that's precisely why I care - the whole thing is pretty much useless if it can't be used to write an UI that's fast enough to run on any smartphone.

JohnL: I hope you're right, but initial results don't look promising; the Long class from Closure was slower than the native Number type by a factor of 15 to 30 in my tests. Will look into it though.

Comment: Why not just "target" 32 bit -- basically, you rely on a 32 bit GHC, and generate 32 bit code only.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule "Int" should only be used for things where 2^29 is big enough, and apart from that it doesn't matter. Anywhere else use either Integer or one of the Data.Word or Data.Int (Int8, Int16 etc) types. Good examples include most sizes and counts (but not file sizes, which can easily exceed 2^32 these days)

Classic bad example: Control.Concurrent.threadDelay :: Int -> IO ().  The argument is the pause time in uSec. 2^29 uSec = 8.94784853 minutes (according to Google Calculator). The argument should have been Integer, or at least Word64 (584 554.531 years).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript numbers are represented as doubles, so use `Double`.